# Vue.js automatically converting Web Components to elements

Tags: vuejs2, custom-element

I am using Vue.js in an app, but only for parts that require more logic. Otherwise I stick with Web components.

I hit an issue when I am try to mix those. I have a Web Component that only extends an existing element (input in my case). Without Vue.js everything works as expected, but inside Vue, "is" is a Vue attribute ([docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is)) and thus entire element is converted to a name element as specified there.

To give an example, HTML without Vue.js stays as is:

```
<input type="text" is="test-autocomplete" name="search" />
```

But with Vue.js, it becomes:

```
<test-autocomplete type="text" name="search"></test-autocomplete>
```

Which is wrong. It should stay the same as in first case.
Searching on the web, the only solution I found is to set ignored elements as:

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'test-autocomplete',
  /^test-/
];
```

But it does not work and here is where I started running out of ideas. Any help from this point how to make it work is appreciated!

I created a minimum fiddle, where my issue is reproduced. I'd expect both outputs to render identically.
https://jsfiddle.net/q2cre9po/2/

Comment: Forcing vue to ignore certain tags that are natively belonging to web component is the only way: there is no other way VueJS knows what is a web component or not.

Comment: The issue I am facing here is that they are *not* ignored, although I expect them to be. So is it a Vue bug?